# a work of art represents both more and less than a simulacrum of pleasure

Tags: meaning-in-context

I still have problem with the meaning of the first sentence of this paragraph, although I think I have got closer to its real meaning. Am I right with this interpretation?

My understanding:

"Much like a work of science, a work of art looks for something beyond mere presentation of pleasure. Because, the viewpoint of observer has a key role in the definition of its values, ...."

Context:

Much like a work of science, a work of art represents both more and less than a simulacrum of pleasure – it is foregrounded by the values relative to the value-maker, attests to multiple layers of possible meaning, is inevitable only in that it privileges the mores of a particular culture at a particular time in history and, within its shifting temporary context, it is ripe for continual reinterpretation and validation.

Comment: It's circumlocutious purple prose... but sure, you nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not "right" in your "interpretation" of the first sentence for two reasons.  The first is that there is no "right" or "wrong" interpretation because the sentence has no discernible meaning.  The second is that what you've given isn't an interpretation, but a permutation of Ede's words with a few of your own thrown in.  What you confront is a string of words, each of which has an agreed-upon meaning (more or less) that have been arranged according to the rules of English syntax.  For example, the words obey S-V-O order, adjectives precede the nouns they modify, and so on.

But that doesn't mean that the arrangement has to make any sense.

When you encounter English text that does make sense, you will be able to rephrase it without changing its meaning and negate its meaning entirely by using the same syntactical rules that govern the original.  Take

> We hold these truths to be self-evident:  that all men are created
>   equal....

Rephrase:

> It is considered clear that no person is better than another.

Transposed to the passive; took the opposite of all and thus needed the opposite of equal; substituted the singular indeterminate ("person") for the plural ("all").

Negation:

> There is evidence that some people are worthier than others.

I'll leave the grammatical changes as an exercise for the interested reader.

This doesn't mean that ambiguity doesn't exist.  What does "equal" mean in this context?  Clearly people aren't of equal height or skill or intelligence.  If it means "equal before the law," how does that work in practice?  When we say "men," does that include women?  How about slaves?   (I've given some ambiguities in vocabulary.  Sometimes ambiguity arises from the grammar as well.)  These are discussions we can hold about and beyond the text.

You can't do that with Ede's prose.  Suppose that you hadn't read anything from *Art and Science*, and I had given you her version as above and mine, which read

> A work of art represents neither more nor less than a simulacrum of
>   pleasure but instead resides in plane of representation in which there is
>   no comparable ordering determined by magnitude.

Would you have been able to tell which was the "authentic" text?